# Position of elements in Panel GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I want to know if it's possible to position different elements in a panel like an `horizontalPanel` for example.

In my Java code, I have an `horizontalPanel` with two elements, one image and one Label.

I want that my image to be in the left of the Panel and the Label in the middle.

For example:

```
    HorizontalPanel pHeader = new HorizontalPanel();

    Image movieData = new Image();
    movieData.setUrl("http://i.myegy.to/images/1c58b25ce86e.original.png");

    Label titleHead = new Label ("Movies");

    pHeader.add(movieData);
    pHeader.add(titleHead);
```

How can I place these both elements?

Thank you for your help.

Mickey74

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setCellHorizontalAlignment](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CellPanel.html#setCellHorizontalAlignment%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget,%20com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasHorizontalAlignment.HorizontalAlignmentConstant%29):

```
pHeader.setCellHorizontalAlignment(movieData, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
pHeader.setCellHorizontalAlignment(titleHead, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```